# .htaccess rewrite Wordpress category to page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a little problen with URL structure because i am using a custom structure of my Wordpress page.

Currently i am using normal pages as categories.

```
www.domain.tld/my_page
```

This page contains all posts from a normal Wordpress category. Page is autogenerated with plugin. My problem is when i am using breadcrumbs, when i go into post i get following breadcrumbs.

```
Home > Category > Post
```

This should be

```
Home > Category > Post (where category should link to my_page instead of category)
```

I can manage this with normal rewritetrule in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/name_of_category/ http://domain.tld/name_of_category/ [R=301,L]
```

Is is possible to make rewritetule in .htaccess that removes /category/ completely from URL strucure? This will make my structure work like it should, without me having to ad new rule in .htaccess everytime i ad new category.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function kill_category_base ($string) {
   $string = str_replace('category/', '', $string);
   return $string;
}
add_filter('category_link', 'kill_category_base');
```

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(page/([0-9]+)|feed)$ index.php/category/$1/$2 [L]  # redirect category    pages and feeds
```

Found here [Remove Categoriy Suffix Permalink](http://joanpiedra.com/wordpress/remove-category-suffix-permalink/)